# How to set PayPal shipping costs with JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, paypal, twig

I have a Form that is in html.twig format. In that form there is a for loop that shows every product we have.

Corresponding to that Form there is a chckForm() Functions which calculates or to be more precise adds shipping costs to a product when a user buys it.

The shipping costs dropdown has 2 Values: "12,00" or "18.50". This Value is then added to the order.

The problem is that if users buys more of our products than the shipping cost is always added again instead of only being added once to the whole order.

Form Code in html.twig:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
{% for item in page.header.paypal.items %}
    {% set image = media['user://pages/images/'~item.image].resize(52) %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ image }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.description }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ item.amount|number_format(2,',') }}&nbsp;{{ currency_sign }}</td>
        <td>
            <form name="{{ item.name }}"
                  id="{{ item.name }}"
                  target="paypal"
                  action="{{ page.header.paypal.action }}"
                  method="post"
                  onsubmit="return chkForm('{{ item.name }}');">
                <input src="/images/button-basket.png" name="submit"
                       alt="In den Warenkorb" title="In den Warenkorb"
                       type="image">
                <input name="add" value="1" type="hidden">
                <input name="cmd" value="_cart" type="hidden">
                <input name="business" value="{{ page.header.paypal.business }}" type="hidden">
                <input name="item_name" value="{{ item.name }} - {{ item.description }}" type="hidden">
                <input name="amount" value="{{ item.amount|number_format(2,'.') }}" type="hidden">
                <input name="no_shipping" value="0" type="hidden">
                <input name="shipping" value="0.00" type="hidden"> 
                <input name="no_note" value="1" type="hidden">
                <input name="currency_code" value="{{ page.header.paypal.currency_code }}" type="hidden">
                <input name="lc" value="{{ page.header.paypal.lc }}" type="hidden">
                <input name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF" type="hidden">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

and the corresponding JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
function chkForm(form)
{
    var shippingCosts = $('#shippingCosts').val();      // value from shipping dropdown 12 or 18.50         
    var shippingField = $('#'+form+' input[name=shipping]'); // hidden input > 0.00 
    
    shippingField.val(shippingCosts);

    console.log("value1:" + shippingCosts);
    
    return true;
}
```

Now I need to solve that problem by somehow saying that the shipping value should only be added once in the .js Function. I tried a few things with some if`s but it didn't work.

Another way could be to just add the products with the price and then at the end if the User presses the final BUY so on the PayPal checkout site he is asked to either specify shipping costs as 12$ or 18.50$ - but I don't know if that is possible with PayPal.

Comment: You should not use the client-side paypal integration as this allows users to modify the amount and shipping themselves. You should use the [server-side integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/server-integration/) and calculate the correct amount and shipping on the server-side before sending it to PayPal to ensure the customers pays the correct price

Comment: @DarkBee that's a deprecated guide with old information. The current PayPal Checkout documentation for a server-side integration is here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls for the backend, and here for the approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Okay guys thank you for your information I will look into it :)

Comment: Mh I really dont know how I would transition my current code and logic to use the new approach. Do I need to build a REST API ? even though I am not using a DB in the background?

Comment: Ah a quick question: Is it possible to tell paypal that the user has to check 1 of 2 shipping costs bevore purchasing so on the paypal side? I have seen something where you can setip the add to cart button.. but I dont know if I can just pass the prices and tell paypal to add a shipping at the end.

Comment: I am looking at the code but I am not understanding how PayPal even knows where the shippingcosts come from and how they know that this value is getting added as shippingcosts to the product.